# Is this fiber asbestos or an old paper material?

Tags: asbestos

[image]

Taking this paper down that is covering Shiplap. It looks like the paper I made in elementary school when you tear pieces of construction paper and put it in a blender to make new paper. House was built in 1933 so I’m worried it could be asbestos. Old owner said she thinks it’s just paper. Please help :)

Comment: It's impossible to tell from appearance.  Have a sample tested by a lab so that you know for sure.  If it is, get it professionally abated by a licensed contractor.

Comment: Normally paper under siding was tar paper or “felt” I have seen asbestos your photo is not clear enough to tell but appears to be the correct color and texture from what I can see, I would get it tested before doing any more work on it. Sheet asbestos is just like the paper you made in school but probably thicker.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Does it burn? If so, it's not asbestos.